# Python: Access saved points from 2d array in 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I got a 2d numpy array `(shape(y,x)=601,1200)` and a 3d numpy array `(shape(z,y,x)=137,601,1200)`.

In my 2d array, I saved the `z` values at the `y, x` point which I now want to access from my 3d array and save it into a new 2d array.

I tried something like this without success.

```
levels = array2d.reshape(-1)
y = np.arange(601)
x = np.arange(1200)
newArray2d=oldArray3d[levels,y,x]
```

> IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (721200,) (601,) (1200,)

I don't want to try something with loops, so is there any faster method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the data you have:

```
x_len = 12     # In your case, 1200
y_len = 6      # In your case, 601
z_len = 3      # In your case, 137

import numpy as np
my2d = np.random.randint(0,z_len,(y_len,x_len))
my3d = np.random.randint(0,5,(z_len,y_len,x_len))
```

This is one way to build your new 2d array:

```
yindices,xindices = np.indices(my2d.shape)
new2d = my3d[my2d[:], yindices, xindices]
```

**Notes:**

1. We're using Integer Advanced Indexing.
2. This means we index the 3d array `my3d` with 3 integer index arrays.
3. For more explanation on how integer array indexing works, please refer to [my answer on this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054603/index-a-3d-array-with-2d-array-numpy/55055614#55055614)
4. In your attempt, there was no need to reshape your 2d with `reshape(-1)`, since the shape of the integer index array that we pass, will (after any broadcasting) become the shape of the resulting 2d array.
5. Also, in your attempt, your second and third index arrays need to have opposite orientations. That is, they must be of shape `(y_len,1)` and `(1, x_len)`. Notice the different positions of the `1`. This ensures that these two index arrays will get broadcasted

Comment: Quick and easy. Thanks @fountainhead!

Answer (score 0):

There's some vagueness in your question, but I think you want to advanced indexing like this:

```
In [2]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)                                      
In [3]: levels = np.random.randint(0,4,(3,2))                                   
In [4]: levels                                                                  
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 1],
       [0, 2]])
In [5]: arr                                                                     
Out[5]: 
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]],

       [[12, 13],
        [14, 15],
        [16, 17]],

       [[18, 19],
        [20, 21],
        [22, 23]]])
In [6]: arr[levels, np.arange(3)[:,None], np.arange(2)]                         
Out[6]: 
array([[ 6, 13],
       [20,  9],
       [ 4, 17]])
```

`levels` is (3,2).  I created the other 2 indexing arrays to they broadcast with it (3,1) and (2,).  The result is a (3,2) array of values from `arr`, selected by their combined indices.

Comment: I went with fountainhead's solution. But also thanks to you! @hpaulj